# mySQL finding the top 3 posts depending on the number of comments on them

Tags: mysql, sql

In my database there are 2 tables relating to posts the users make: tblPosts - which contains the information about a post a user has made. And tblComments which contains the comments made by users.

tblPosts:

[image: has this structure]

tblComments:

[image: has this structure]

My goal is to select the top 3 most popular posts, these are the 3 posts with the most comments on them.

I am however stumped on how to do this and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation, `order by`, and `limit`:

```
select post_id, count(*) as num_comments
from comments c
group by post_id
order by count(*) desc
limit 3;
```